# How to get row elements from extjs 4.2 grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid in Extjs 4.2 and I need to get the row elements so I can compare row values and then call .addCls() on specific rows.  I have tried .getNodes() but I cannot call .addCls() on a node.

I am already doing this with form fields but I need to do it with grid rows too:

```
myForm.getForm().getFields().items[i].getEl().dom
```

**UPDATE:** This is what I am doing with form fields and I need to do something similar with grid cells.  Initially, I said I needed to add a class to the grid row but really I will need to add a class to the grid cell.

```
var myFormAItems = myFormA.getForm().getFields().items;
var myFormBItems = myFormB.getForm().getFields().items;

for (i = 0; i < prodItems.length; i++) {
   if (myFormAItems[i].getEl().dom.textContent != myFormBItems[i].getEl().dom.textContent) {
        myFormAItems[i].addCls('highlightDiff');
   };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want can be achieved using `grid.getView().getNodes()` to get the grid's rows and then use `query()` to get the `<td>` tags.

If you just need to apply custom classes, this is simpler:

You can add CSS classes for each row in the grid overwriting the function `getRowClass()` from the grid view. The option `viewConfig` from the grid config is used for this.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // other options
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
            if (record.get('property') == 'value'){
                return 'my-custom-class';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6ph).

Comment: I really need an array of rows for one grid so I can compare it to an array of rows from another grid and then add a class if there is a difference.  I'm not seeing how I can do that with getRowClass.  Isn't there an items array that I can get to from a grid with all of the rows?  It seems like there should be.

Comment: What is exactly the difference you are looking for? Can you give me an example of what are you trying to do? Get the rows of a grid as the rows of a `HTML` table can't be done as far as I know, what you can do is get the records of the associated store of each grid.

Comment: I have updated my question with more information about what I am trying to do.  Sorry for the lack of info in the original question.